Android aab updates
I am working on a android quiz game app. First version will come out with 2 categories of questions. I was wondering how to add an update with another category of questions without losing progress for players who already played first 2 categories on Google Play Store.
I am first time android developer, and I do not have solution for this problem.

Just release an updated version with the same packageName. As you should have recognized as Android user, apps don't loose their data if you install an update. So you just have to make sure that the update can read the data created by the first version and then update it to the current version (data migration on first start of the updated version).

Thank you for your answer. Can you please tell me what do you mean by "data migration on first start of the updated version", and can you please describe it to me?
